# How to limit Wordpress Cron jobs to only run on production server?

Tags: wordpress, cron

Using the [WP Crontrol plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) I schedule a process that sends out reminders emails to users. It is working well, but everytime I need to test something using actual data, I am scared that the system will send out reminders that should not have been sent or have already been sent from the live system.

After restoring the backup from the production server, I quickly go to the SMTP plugin I am using and select the option that drops emails sent. That does the job, but there is still a risk that something gets sent before I manage to do that.

So, I am considering my options. One is to wrap the reminder function into a check to see if it is the production server. And only run the function when it is.
I could check using `home_url()`, and I know it will work because I use this approach for something else.

But I feel there is a better and more correct way, and kindly ask for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this approach in my projects to separate the code that runs according to the development environment. First I create a constant in the file wp-config.php with the name WP_ENVIRONMENT and assign the value of development to it and then I recognize the execution environment using two helper functions :

```
function prefix_is_development() {
     return defined("WP_ENVIRONMENT") && "development" === 
     strtolower(WP_ENVIRONMENT);
}

function prefix_is_production() {
  return !defined("WP_ENVIRONMENT") || "production" === 
  strtolower(WP_ENVIRONMENT);
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean Siavash. Thanks for sharing. I was thinking about this ENV approach, but the wp-config.php is part of the backup, and so it will contain the production value when restored and potentially execute cron jobs immediately.

Comment: Thanks Carter ... Well if you have backup you can change functions logic, for example for prefix_is_development you can write something like this :  return !defined("WP_ENVIRONMENT") || "development" === 
     strtolower(WP_ENVIRONMENT); in this implementation if you restore backup ... this function return true and cron jobs will not run